# How to resize UINavigationController in a storyboard editor

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

When I want resize an UIViewController in a storyboard editor window I do:

- I put size to "freeForm" in the UIViewController  attributes inspector
- I select the view and resize her with the size inspector

after that, the uiViewController is resized in storyboard window.

Next, I select the view controller, click on: edit > embeded in> Navigation Controller and the problem is that navigation controller is in full size and not the same size that UIViewController. I don't find how resize this navigation controller.

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to do? As you know, iOS apps run in full screen, if your navigation controller is the start point of your app, it can't start in a smaller window than full screen.

Comment: I have the exact same issue for designing popovers for iPad. Popover views does only cover a (usually) small portion of the screen. In the storyboard, you can easily resize view controllers, but not navigation controllers. This is a real pain since you can't just add a navigation bar to your view controller if you use static table view cells which must be in a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't resize a NavigationController - it is not a ViewController. It controls the navigation of ViewControllers. You specify an initial ViewController (the one you embedded into it will be the initial viewController by default). You then create segues into other ViewControllers.

Comment: Actually UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController.. so "it is not a ViewController" is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

There's a trick to get around this limitation. Add a view controller to your storyboard and then add a Container View as a subview to it's view. Size that container view to the size you want the navigation controller (and it's children) and then control drag from the container controller to your navigation controller. You can then instantiate the navigation controller by identifier and the container view controller will be ignored.