# Size of Navigation Controller inside Popover on Storyboard canvas in Interface Builder

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, interface-builder, xcode5

**Note:** this question is *not* about the size of views in the running app. It is strictly about the size of the Navigation Controller representation on the canvas in Interface Builder.

This image illustrates the problem behavior in Interface Builder.

[image: Wrong Navigation Controller size on canvas]

I have not found a way to make the Navigation Controller representation smaller. As you can imagine, an iPad app with lots of Navigation Controllers in lots of Popovers causes the Storyboard canvas to get very crowded.

Note that in order to correct the size of the Navigation Controller's root view controller, I had to adjust the root view controller's *Simulated Metrics Size* to "Freeform", and then manually specify it's root view size to match the Container View size.

This illustration shows the desired behavior of the Navigation Controller element.

[image: Proper sizing of Navigation Controller on canvas]

This illustration also gives a hint as to the cause of the problem. The size of the Container View does not trickle down to the Navigation Controller element if there is an interposing view controller.

I have found 3 similar questions, but none of them provide illustrations, and none directly address that this problem is still present in Xcode 5.

1. [Resize NavigationController in InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988168/resize-navigationcontroller-in-interfacebuilder)
2. [How to resize UINavigationController in a storyboard editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195143/how-to-resize-uinavigationcontroller-in-a-storyboard-editor)
3. [Popover size with UINavigationController in Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024170/popover-size-with-uinavigationcontroller-in-storyboard)

I have found no answers on the Apple Developer Forums from the past 90 days.

So the question is, is there some control or setting in Interface Builder that I am overlooking that will solve my problem?

One of the answers to the question listed above provides a trick which involves adding an unused View Controller and Container View for every Navigation Controller, but that is unsatisfactory because adding cruft to the Storyboard is worse than having oversized Navigation Controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your specific situation, but after much searching I discovered that (at least in Xcode 5.1) there's a "View Controller" panel in the storyboard sidebar with a "Simulated Size" entry - pick "Freeform" and set your width and height as you wish.

[image: screen shot of View Controller 'Simulated Size' controls]

Comment: It took me 10 whole minutes to realize that you were on the **Size** Inspector not the Attributes Inspector. I'm on 5.1 now also. I suspect that in 5.0 and earlier the Size Inspector for VCs was blank. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found a half-fix that makes this problem a bit more palatable: You can set the simulated metrics of the navigation controller to be Master (which is 320 points wide, portrait or landscape height) or Form Sheet (which is 540 x 620).

Then in the root view controller it contains, you can set the size you want (as you did) by making it freeform.

It looks like the size of this view is used for the popover by default (or you can set it explicitly on this view controller via the "Popover: Use Explicit Size" setting). Note, though, that if you are showing the navigation bar in the simulated metrics of this view controller, you have to compensate by subtracting the bar's height from the popover explicit size of the view or hiding it in the simulated metrics of the popover root view controller.